# How to ignore column names in Hibernate

Tags: hibernate

I had a situation where my java application need to connect two different databases

database1:

TableName:User
column names:userId,FirstName,StartDate

database2:

TableName:User
column names:userId,UserName,StartDate

I used Hibernate(ORM) where my entity class looks like

```
@Entity
public class User {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "User_ID")
    private String userName;

    private String name;

    @Column(name = "Start_Date")
    private String startDate;

}
```

The problem i m facing is second attribute name is different above tables
so i m unable to map this entity class with them in generic way.

help me in figuring

is there a way in hibernate to ignore column name or (two names for single column) so that i can map single entity to both tables

Answer (score 0):

do not take property in your entity which have different your schema. like below.

```
@Entity
public class User {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "User_ID")
    private String userName;

    @Column(name = "Start_Date")
    private String startDate;

}
```